# how to get errors written to process.stderr to show up in the AWS Lambda console?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

A 3rd party library beyond my control (i.e.: [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)) is logging errors to `process.stderr`.

While running in Aws Lambda, I want to log these errors so I can inspect them. ( process.stderr and process.stdout do NOT show up in the Lambda console)

The way to do that in Lambda afaik is to use console.error / console.log, etc. which have special implementations in Lambda.

So best bet I figured was to do something like:

```
process.stderr.on('data', function (buffer) {
  console.error(buffer.toString())
});
```

But this does not give me any results either.

How do I get errors written to `process.stderr` to show up in the Aws lambda console?

Comment: Are you trying to write to the console from inside `page.evaluate()`?

Comment: @Mark_M: nope I'm not. I'm trying to log chrome crashes with the `dumpio: true` argument, which outputs errors of the child process (chrome) to `process.stderr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to fix it by overwriting process.stderr.write as follows:

```
process.stderr.write = (function () {
  return function (buffer) {
    //NOTE: console.error doens't use process.stderr in Aws lambda, so this doesn't result in a livelock
    console.error(buffer.toString()); 
  };
}());
```